# WP: property split() cannot be read property

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have a problem with a piece of jQuery code on Wordpress. The method split() cannot be read.
This is the code:

```
     var backImages = jQuery('#backgrounds').data('backgrounds').split(',');

    jQuery.backstretch(backImages, {
    fade: 500,
    duration: 4000
});

if(!jQuery('#color-overlay').length){jQuery('body').addClass('no-overlay');}
```

I inspected the code using the console and I get following error: 
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined**
Outside WP the script works properly.

Comment: Can you add your html here as well? The relevant bits? Looks like there is  either no element with id backgrounds, or that element does not have an attribute 'data-backgrounds' or you have multiple elements with id backgrounds the first of which has this issue.

Comment: Read the error, it means that `.data(backgrounds)` is undefined.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I forgot to add .data(backgrounds)...